# React native 0.59.9 app crashing in android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

The app crashes when I signed in and in the main application but no problems when I am in the login screen with no error what so ever and a few seconds the app crash. The IOS is doing okay and running perfectly.

React Native Environment Info:
  System:
      OS: Windows 10
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz
      Memory: 1.19 GB / 7.85 GB
    Binaries:
      Yarn: 1.19.2 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.11.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "FitnessCapital",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start -- --reset-cache",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "sh ./fix.sh"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@feathersjs/authentication-client": "^1.0.2",
    "@feathersjs/feathers": "^3.1.7",
    "@feathersjs/socketio-client": "^1.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^2.0.0",
    "appcenter": "^1.6.0",
    "appcenter-analytics": "^1.6.0",
    "appcenter-crashes": "^1.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.13.2",
    "instabug-reactnative": "^8.3.2",
    "mobx": "4.3.1",
    "mobx-react": "5.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.8.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.59.9",
    "react-native-amplitude-analytics": "^0.2.6",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-google-signin": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.24.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.27.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.493",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-share": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-smtp-mailer": "^1.1.8",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.5",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-video": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^2.6.0",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
    "victory-native": "^31.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      ".\\node_modules\\appcenter\\test\\AppCenterMock.js",
      ".\\node_modules\\appcenter-analytics\\test\\AppCenterAnalyticsMock.js",
      ".\\node_modules\\appcenter-crashes\\test\\AppCenterCrashesMock.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

adroid/build.gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

def versionOverrides = [
"com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk": "4.37.0",
]

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "15.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
subprojects {
    if (project.name.contains('react-native-image-picker')) {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/" }
            }

        }
    }
    afterEvaluate {project ->
    // force libs to use recent buildtools
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion = 28  // change to match your desired version
                buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3" // ....
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://sdks.instabug.com/nexus/repository/instabug-cp"
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def overrideVersion = versionOverrides[details.requested.group + ":" + details.requested.name]

        if (overrideVersion != null && details.requested.version != overrideVersion) {
            details.useVersion overrideVersion
        }
    }
}

}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"

}
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code there is a *ObjectName*.placedValue or similar. Can you show that part of code?

Comment: And another thing, don't accept an answer if it hasn't resolved your problem, like that everyone is just passing your question as it shows that it has been answered

Answer (score 0):

You can check error detail in Logcat on Android Studio.
If there is no workaround for this error, please post it here, I will do my best to help you resolve it

Comment: "error in getLeaderboardRank Error: Cannot read property 'placedValue' of undefined"  - we got this error on IOS also but its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when the debug build works and the app crashes with no errors in release build it is due to proguard. On your android/app/build.gradle try this settings and build you release app to test whether this is the case

```
    buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        // JUST LEAVE THE ABOVE LINE AND COMMENT EVERYTHING ELSE IN THIS BLOCK
        // minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
```

and configure your proguard. Usually, you have to add the following line of code,

```
-keep class installed.package.identifier.**  { *; }
```

installed.package.identifier is the package that was being affected by proguard causing the crash. You need to figure which package is likely causing it and add its bundle identifier so that proguard won't remove the required class.